# Solving an exponential equation

Tags: equation-solving

When I try to solve this exponential equation:

```
Solve[E^-t^2 (2 - E^-t^2)+E^(-2 t - (3 t^2)/2) (2 - E^-t^2) (2 - E^(-2 t - t^2/2)) (1-E^-t^2 (2 - E^-t^2)) == 0.1, t, Reals]
```

[image]

I don't get any solution despite waiting for a long time

How can I solve it and is there another way
Please Help

Comment: Use: `Solve[E^-t^2 (2 - E^-t^2) + 
    E^(-2 t - (3 t^2)/2) (2 - E^-t^2) (2 - E^(-2 t - t^2/2)) (1 - 
       E^-t^2 (2 - E^-t^2)) == 1/10 && -10 < t < 10, t, Reals]`

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following. First of all, define the auxiliary function $f(t)$ as follows

```
f[t_]:=E^-t^2 (2 - E^-t^2)+E^(-2 t - (3 t^2)/2) (2 - E^-t^2) (2 - E^(-2 t - t^2/2)) (1-E^-t^2 (2 - E^-t^2))-0.1
```

Thus, the equation you want to solve is $f(t)=0$. The plot of $f(t)$ may indicate if there are solutions to this equation. Indeed, use

```
 Plot[f[t], {t, -1, 2}]
```

[image]

We explicitly see that one solution is roughly located at $x\approx-0.8$ and the second one at $x\approx 1.5$. This piece of information is useful.

Now, by means of `FindRoot` one can obtain the roots using those rough estimates to establish an appropriate domain to look for the root. For example, the negative root is contained in [-1,0]. Thus,

```
  FindRoot[f[t] == 0, {t, -1, 0}] 
  {t -> -0.751553}
```

Analogously, for the positive root. Of course you need to check whether there are more roots in an extended domain and not only inside [-1,2].